# Ajax - how to check returned HTML for CSS class?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using Ajax to post to a .Net MVC controller. It returns HTML to be displayed on a section of the page. What I need to do is somehow determine if the HTML contains a class name so I can use that to update another section of the web page.

This is my Ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        $("#validation-remarks").html(response);
        $("#updateMessage").html(response);

        console.log(response);

        var html = $.parseHTML(response);
        //somehow check the HTML for a value

        $("#divLoading").hide();
    }
```

It returns the one of the following Bootstrap HTML.

```
@if (Model.IsSuccessful)
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        @Model.UpdateMessage
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>@Model.UpdateMessage</strong> 

        <div class="pt-2">
            @Html.Raw(Model.ValidationMessage)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What I would like to do is see if the HTML returned contains either the "alert-success" or "alert-danger" class. I can then update a message on another part of the page with some text like "Success" or "Fail" depending on the CSS class name I find.

I saw a jQuery.parseHTML() but I'm not sure what to do with it from there to dtermine if the HTML contains one of those class files.

**UPATE WITH JSON**

Tried using JSON but an error with it. If I can get that to work I think ultimately it's the best way to look to see if it's valid versus looking for a css class.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);

alert("json value: " + json.IsValid);

if (json.IsValid === false) {
    alert("Valid is false");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you might find [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) helpful.

> **.hasClass( className )**
>   Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

Below, I convert the response into a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) and then test that object for class names.

```js
var responses = [
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    @Model.UpdateMessage
  </div>`,
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>@Model.UpdateMessage</strong> 
    <div class="pt-2">
      @Html.Raw(Model.ValidationMessage)
    </div>
  </div>`,
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-something-else">
  </div>`
];

var $output = $('#output');

$.each(responses, function(k, response) {

  var $html = $(response);

  if ($html.hasClass('alert-success')) {
    $output.append('<p>' + k + ') Contains Success</p>');
  } else if ($html.hasClass('alert-danger')) {
    $output.append('<p>' + k + ') Contains Danger</p>');
  } else {
    $output.append('<p>' + k + ') Contains Neither</p>');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

---

If you are not using jQuery, JavaScript's [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) might be useful, as mentioned in the [answer from @TehseenJohnson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544633/924299).

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```js
var responses = [
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    @Model.UpdateMessage
  </div>`,
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>@Model.UpdateMessage</strong> 
    <div class="pt-2">
      @Html.Raw(Model.ValidationMessage)
    </div>
  </div>`,
  `<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-something-else">
  </div>`
];

var output = document.getElementById('output');

responses.forEach(function(response, k) {

  var elm = document.createElement('p');

  if (response.indexOf('alert-success') > -1) {
    var content = document.createTextNode(k + ') Contains Success');
  } else if (response.indexOf('alert-danger') > -1) {
    var content = document.createTextNode(k + ') Contains Danger');
  } else {
    var content = document.createTextNode(k + ') Contains Neither');
  }

  elm.appendChild(content);
  output.appendChild(elm);

});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: The .hasClass works and currently using it, however, I see it's returning JSON so I tried parsing JSON and then look at the IsValid property. I get an error with that. I put the updated code in the original question. Do you see why that JSON code would throw an error? From the jQuery docs it looks like it should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem that your script returns data in JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily use Javascript to search for that CSS class. Like `response.indexOf('NameOfClass') > -1`. I hope it make sense.

Comment: This works as well but I like the .hasClass option. Seems a little more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it that the `alert` div is the root element of the response, `isSuccess` and `isDanger` below will return a boolean.

```
var html = $.parseHTML(response);
//test for '.alert-success'
var isSuccess = $( html ).is('.alert-success');
//test for '.alert-danger'
var isDanger = html.is('.alert-danger');
```

> **.is( selector )**
>   Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one
>   of these elements matches the given arguments. http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: Using jQuery 3.0.0 I get an error saying "html.is is not a function".

Comment: What if you replace `$.parseHTML` with `$`? I need to play with `3.0.0` some more.

Comment: `parseHTML` returns a set of DOM nodes. To use `is()`, you'll need a jQuery object. `$($.parseHTML(response));` or just `$(response);` should work.